# Node.Js Express-Generator Project generator error (encoding && encoding.toLowerCase()

Tags: node.js, express-generator

Installed the latest version of **Node.Js()** and npm package**(1.2.10)**
When I ran the express command to generate the project it throws me below error

```
buffer.js:240
  switch (encoding && encoding.toLowerCase()) {
                               ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase'
    at Function.Buffer.isEncoding (buffer.js:240:32)
    at assertEncoding (fs.js:98:27)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:908:3)
    at write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:273:6)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:233:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:288:11
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:26
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
    at process._makeCallback (node.js:321:24)
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: How do i get rid of this error.. so that I can generate project with all dependices

Comment: can you show the code that you are using, there isn't enough information there to diagnose the issue

Comment: I have not written any code test .. I am using a command express to create a empty project. When I am using this command it fails to create a empty project.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded by Build using this commands and it worked

```
sudo npm cache clean -f 
sudo npm install -g n 
sudo n stable
Reinstall Express and Express-Generator 
sudo npm install -g express
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```